# Examples in docplex to use the user cut callback method technology

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, docplex

Please can you provide an example of how this can used in a python notebook environment with docplex. I see examples with java on ATSP problem. The point is I do not know how to create these cuts upfront. Given a LP root node, I can generate the cut. So, "add_user_cut_constraint(cut_ct, name=None)" should in a way take in as input the root node. How do I retrieve that in a generic way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this code in my `contribs` repository:

`https://github.com/PhilippeCouronne/docplex_contribs/blob/master/docplex_contribs/src/cut_callback.py`

It is not a notebook, but you'll get the idea on how to interface callbacks with Docplex.